# Setting Value in Kivy Canvas

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem that can't solve.Problem is this:

When you run this code,

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    my_colors: app.a1,app.a2,app.a3,app.a4
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.my_colors
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
"""

class d(App):
    def build(self):
        self.a1 = "0.5"
        self.a2 = "0.7"
        self.a3 = "0.222222"
        self.a4 = "0.3456"
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

d().run()
```

I get this error:

```
 File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid2/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 831, in _build_canvas
     '{}: {}'.format(e.__class__.__name__, e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 9:
 ...
       7:    canvas.before:
       8:        Color:
 >>    9:            rgba: yardim.my_colors
      10:        Rectangle:
      11:            pos: self.pos
 ...
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
   File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid2/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 826, in _build_canvas
     setattr(instr, key, value)
   File "kivy/graphics/context_instructions.pyx", line 262, in kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Color.rgba.__set__ (kivy/graphics/context_instructions.c:6428)
```

In shortly,code is give type error.Can you show my wrongs me?

Comment: `yardim.my_colors1` is defined as `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

Since the root widget, *BoxLayout* doesn't have a property with the name, *my_colors*, Kivy automatically created an *ObjectProperty* and added it to the widget. This resulted in the following error,

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

[Kivy Language » Syntax of a kv File](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html)

> If the widget doesn’t have a property with the given name, an
>   ObjectProperty will be automatically created and added to the widget.

## Solution 1

1. Add a class for the root widget.
2. Declare *my_colors* as a *ListProperty* at class level.

## Solution 2

Use ***set <key> <expr>*** to set a global value.

```
#:set my_colors (app.a1, app.a2, app.a3, app.a4)
```

or

```
#:set my_colors [app.a1, app.a2, app.a3, app.a4]
```

## Example

### Solution 1 - main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
RootWidget:
    orientation: "vertical"

    my_colors: [app.a1, app.a2, app.a3, app.a4]

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.my_colors
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
"""


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    my_colors = ListProperty([])


class d(App):

    def build(self):
        self.a1 = "0.5"
        self.a2 = "0.7"
        self.a3 = "0.222222"
        self.a4 = "0.3456"
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


d().run()
```

### Solution 2 - main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
#:set my_colors (app.a1, app.a2, app.a3, app.a4)

BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: my_colors
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
"""


class d(App):

    def build(self):
        self.a1 = "0.5"
        self.a2 = "0.7"
        self.a3 = "0.222222"
        self.a4 = "0.3456"
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


d().run()
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: I was researching this since a week.I thank for your help.